# ros_canopen with lwa4p initialization fails

Tags: ros, ros-canopen, schunk, controller-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to initialize my lwa4p arm as described on the [ros_canopen wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_canopen#Usage), but it seems that I am missing something.

When calling

```
rosservice call /arm/driver/init
```

I get

```
success: 
  data: False
error_message: 
  data: CAN init failed
```

Also, I constantly receive

```
[ INFO] [1424269803.902373134]: waitForService: Service [/arm/controller_manager/load_controller] has not been advertised, waiting...
```

with `arm/joint_state_controller_spawner` restarting after some time.
Is this expected behaviour? What am I missing?

Note: I also failed to run

```
sudo ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 500000
```

as it returns

```
Cannot find device "can0"
```

But I have peak-linux-driver-7.12 installed on my machine, configured as chardev device and I am able to access my arm with another program, so I do not know if this really is a problem. (Same result when using `pcanusb0` instead of `can0`, which is my actual pcan device name.)

Thank you for your support!

Edit: It seems that I had to rebuild my driver as netdev and configure it correctly.

```
sudo ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 500000
```

did not work for me, instead I used

```
sudo ip link set up can0
echo "i 0x001C e" > /dev/pcan32
```

to set baudrate to 500k. When calling the init service, the arm now initializes correctly.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203370/ros_canopen-with-lwa4p-initialization-fails/) by [Marcel Usai](https://answers.ros.org/users/17911/marcel-usai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 200 on 2015-02-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felixwatzlawik](https://answers.ros.org/users/22115/felixwatzlawik/) on 2015-06-23**:
i got the same error and tried your way but cant solve it. can i contact you private?

**Comment by [Marcel Usai](https://answers.ros.org/users/17911/marcel-usai/) on 2015-06-23**:
Which driver do you use? I had to compile the PEAK PCan USB driver as a netdev.
And I always have to set the bitrate to 500k before initializing, which is a bit annyoing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
we do not support the chardev driver anymore.
Please use either the SocketCAN driver built into the linux kernel or recompile the PEAK driver for netdev support.

I have added some more documentation at http://wiki.ros.org/socketcan_interface

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2015-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcel Usai](https://answers.ros.org/users/17911/marcel-usai/) on 2015-02-19**:
Thanks for your answer!
I now loaded the `peak_usb` driver and can find device `can0`. But I still fail to initalize, with `could not reset node '3'` as error message.

**Comment by [Marcel Usai](https://answers.ros.org/users/17911/marcel-usai/) on 2015-02-19**:
Updated my question. Problem is solved, thank you!
But do you have any idea why I could not set the baudrate as described in the documentation?

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2015-02-19**:
Have you verified the bitrate (500k in the example)? What are you node ID (default: 3 to 9)?
The driver is still under development, so please make sure, that you use source code overlays for
https://github.com/ipa320/ros_canopen and  https://github.com/ipa320/ros_control

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2015-02-19**:
The PEAK netdev driver does not support the netlink bitrate setting, but uses a custom chardev interface.
In additon you can pass a default bitrate to the driver module.
However, the mainline kernel driver might be a better choice, especially with recent kernels..